# The difference between these two scheduled method calls - iOS

Tags: ios, methods, facebook-sdk-4.0

I have seen this around a few times but can't seem to find what is the difference between the two ...

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(loginViewFetchedUserInfo:)
                                             name:FBSDKProfileDidChangeNotification
                                           object:nil];

- (void)loginViewFetchedUserInfo:(NSNotification *)notification
```

**and**

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(loginViewFetchedUserInfo)
                                             name:FBSDKProfileDidChangeNotification
                                           object:nil];

- (void)loginViewFetchedUserInfo
```

I know that `(void)methodname:(TYPE *)newName` can pass in a value to the method but I don't know what the difference is in the two above and why you would do the first one (which is used in the Facebook SDK example) over the second one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first method passes the `NSNotification` object to the method. This way allows you to access information about the notification.

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                     selector:@selector(loginViewFetchedUserInfo:)
                                         name:FBSDKProfileDidChangeNotification
                                       nil];
```

For example, if the notification was posted with a `userInfo` dictionary

```
NSDictionary *userInfo = @{@"Blah" : @"foo"};
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:FBSDKProfileDidChangeNotification object:self userInfo:userInfo];
```

and you wanted to access `userInfo` in the method. You can also access the sender of the notification, which would be the notification's `object`.

```
- (void)loginViewFetchedUserInfo:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    NSDictionary *userInfo = notification.userInfo;
    NSObject *sender = notification.object;
}
```

Comment: +1. Your example is a little weird, though, since if you pass that string as an object when calling `addObserver...` you will not receive the notification.  (As it is not triggered on that object.) More typically, it's the userInfo dictionary of the notification you're interested in looking at.

Comment: @JesseRusak Thanks for pointing that out, I don't know why I screwed that up.